# Google Privacy & Messaging JavaScript API - Trigger open message dialog

Tags: adsense

I am referring to https://developers.google.com/funding-choices/fc-api-docs#googlefc-controlledMessagingFunction

I am not able to figure out how to subsequently allow a user to change the privacy settings after consent has been granted by user. I was able to test the ​googlefc.showRevocationMessage() function which triggers the message dialog to open but also resets the user choices. Is there not a way for the user to modify choices previously made and just open the dialog to do so. I don't see any function in googlefc object for that. Does anybody have experience with that? Thank you